# MySQL Nullable FK and the 150 error

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with `create table` statement in MySQL.

The scenario is, I want to have a table `P_CDP` wchich stores some informations, and the table `P_CDPFiles` which stores the data of the uploaded files.

The column `SelectedCDPFileID` by default should be `NULL` unless the user selects some file. Then that column is filled by the file ID. But, I'm still getting the errno 150, why ? I think the FK names are set properly

```
CREATE TABLE `P_CDP` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `P_OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SelectedCDPFileID` int(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_P_CDP_P_Orders` (`P_OrderID`),
  KEY `FK_P_CDP_P_CDPFiles` (`SelectedCDPFileID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDP_P_Orders` FOREIGN KEY (`P_OrderID`) REFERENCES `P_Orders` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDP_P_CDPFiles` FOREIGN KEY (`SelectedCDPFileID`) REFERENCES `P_CDPFiles` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `P_CDPFiles` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FileID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_CDPID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_P_CDPFiles_File` (`FileID`),
  KEY `FK_P_CDPFiles_P_CDP` (`P_CDPID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDPFiles_File` FOREIGN KEY (`FileID`) REFERENCES `File` (`FileID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDPFiles_P_CDP` FOREIGN KEY (`P_CDPID`) REFERENCES `P_CDP` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to reference a table that does not yet exist.

If you *must* have references in both directions between these two tables (which generally indicates quite poor design), you will have to:

1. Create the first table without any reference to the as-yet-undefined table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `P_CDP` (
     `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `P_OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `SelectedCDPFileID` int(11) NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
     KEY `FK_P_CDP_P_Orders` (`P_OrderID`),
     KEY `FK_P_CDP_P_CDPFiles` (`SelectedCDPFileID`),
     CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDP_P_Orders` FOREIGN KEY (`P_OrderID`)
       REFERENCES `P_Orders` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   ```
2. Create the second table, including its reference to the first table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `P_CDPFiles` (
     `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `FileID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `P_CDPID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
     KEY `FK_P_CDPFiles_File` (`FileID`),
     KEY `FK_P_CDPFiles_P_CDP` (`P_CDPID`),
     CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDPFiles_File` FOREIGN KEY (`FileID`)
       REFERENCES `File` (`FileID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
     CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDPFiles_P_CDP` FOREIGN KEY (`P_CDPID`)
       REFERENCES `P_CDP` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   ```
3. Alter the first table to add the intended constraint:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `P_CDP`
     ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_P_CDP_P_CDPFiles` FOREIGN KEY (`SelectedCDPFileID`)
     REFERENCES `P_CDPFiles` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
   ```

Comment: You're right, it should work now. But, why do You  think it's a poor design ?